# Installation C# application without dot net framework

Tags: c#

I have created a new application on C# 2010. After creating a Setup file I came to know that for installation purposes user must have a dot net framework. Is there any way I can get rid of installing dot net framework on a user computer. Each time I try to install my application on the user computer it redirects to install the dot net framework. Any suggestion?

Comment: Running C# app without .Net Framework is like `Eating without food`, `Bathing without Water`?

Comment: Get rid of the system.* references and you are good to go

Comment: @t3hn00b: Its like telling a person to get rid of life from a body and then he will enjoy this world.

Comment: What's next, a question to install the application WITHOUT Windows, on a clean machine? :)

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: No, Next question will be `How to install a C# app on a System which is Off/Dead`

Comment: `it redirects to install dot net framework`.  Yes, nice feature isn't it?  Click Yes.  Or target .NET 3.5

Comment: Use next time  [DELPHI] because this runs on plain windows without runtime, because it compiles to native x86 binary.

Answer (score 3):

Well that's a problem; because of the design of .NET applications.

Here's some references for you:
[Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kx37x362)

> "C# (pronounced "C sharp") is a programming language that is designed for building a variety of applications that run on the .NET Framework." [first sentence]

[Intro to C# and .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1zx9t92)

[image: C# and .NET]

Answer (score 3):

As the comments on the question attempt to imply, the .NET Framework is *required* in order to execute .NET applications.

You have two choices, really:

1. Require that users have the .NET Framework installed.  This is the most common choice, for reasons that will become clear in a moment.  It's not unheard-of to have such requirements.  It's similar to requiring that a user have Windows installed in order to run your Windows application.
2. Distribute the .NET Framework with your application installer.  This is possible, but less often used because the .NET Framework is *large* compared to the average application.  However, if you must do this, then the option is at least available.  Some quick Googling brought me to [this helpful blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/haarongonzalez/archive/2007/04/09/772757.aspx).

Comment: Isn't .NET shipped by default with Windows, at least modern editions?

Comment: Well another alternative is to make the application in unmanaged code so there won't be a need for the framework - quite an expensive ( both time and money ) job.

Comment: @Morawski: Yes its preinstalled on Win7

Comment: @Morawski: But can the OP assume that all users of the application will be running Windows 7 or above?  In my experience XP is still the most widely-used version in the wild.

Comment: Which version though is preinstalled ?

Comment: @David  Not really anymore [Usage share of OSs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems) 38.73% (Windows 7) to 25.86% (Windows XP)

Comment: @David I looked it up. Vista comes with .NET 3.0 by default, but XP does not, indeed. Although I suppose that most WinXP PCs typically have the .NET framework installed anyway (due to having installed at least one .NET application at some point - and these days there's not too many "fresh" XP installs in use)

Comment: @matthewnreid bear in mind that it can vary greatly from country to country

Comment: @Morawski Yes, agreed. That link includes worldwide usage from Gartner research not specific to country. It also doesn't include pirated software in certain countries e.g.
 "For example, in 2009, "U.S. research firm IDC estimated that 80% of software sold in China last year was pirated.""

Comment: @matthewnreid: In India, where i come from its 99%

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal That's interesting.  I found this link which was pretty cool breakdown over the worldwide. [MS Windows Share per Country](http://royal.pingdom.com/2011/12/13/the-state-of-microsoft-windows-in-2011-win-7-and-xp-battle-for-domination/). Short of it is 44% of countries on earth still have Windows XP as most used OS.  It does have China as highest percent country at 74.02% at end of 2011 though.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.  C# is built on the .NET framework, so any C# app requires that a version of .NET be available.  At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#History, you can see what .NET framework versions are available in various versions of Windows.  The short story is that XP doesn't include anything, Vista includes 3.0, and Windows 7 includes 3.5.  If you build for one of these versions, then on those OSes, your users won't need to install anything extra.  Using the Client Profile instead of the full .NET can also help reduce or eliminate installs your users will need to do.

Comment: `C# is built on the .NET framework, so any C# app requires that a version of .NET be available.` Couldn't one develop their C# app for Mono for Windows instead of .NET? Not the most recommendable alternative perhaps, but an alternative nevertheless, unless I'm missing something

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Mono must be installed just like the .NET framework, so I didn't mention it because I considered it more like "a version of .NET" than something completely separate.  It just happens to be a third-party cross-platform implementation of .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No. Its not possible.

To explain it simple terms.

Suppose if you have written only 1 Line of code where you would have simply declared an `int` variable, who will tell OS that it should create a space in memory?

That framework does exactly that creates basic environment to run your app in a System.

**OOPs says about Real-world modeling and Relationships, so let me give you one from it.**

**Think yourself to be the C# app and Mother Nature/Environment(Greenry) to be .Net Environment.(.Net is called an Environment)**

**Can you survive without mother nature? From first second that you are in this world, you breathe. Who provides you that oxygen. MOTHER NATURE**

Comment: It is possible, and you can implement your own basic types (int, string, et cetera). You can develop without .NET completely by removing any references to mscorlib and the other .NET libraries.

Comment: You could make the same argument about a C program, which doesn't need any runtime at all...

Comment: @WillVousden: Is that for me or David Anderson

Answer (score 0):

While creating installation bundle you can add dot net frame work exe file as prerequisites, then while installing your application it can check whether the system having .net framework or not.  if it is not installed it your application can install the frame work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using managed languages to writing applications you agreed to use their vm, c# codes compiles to IL which needs dot net framework for executing.

.net framework by default exists on windows 7,8,8.1 and 10 and I don't think that this is a challenge.

but if you insist on it so there is a way by using Mono, just remove features that does not support in mono from your project.

first install mono and cygwin, then copy your exe and mono.dll file to a folder,  be sure that your file name is not long because in some cases bundling faild,now you can start bundling using mkbundle command.

after bundling finished you have a exe file that can run without .net framework

hope this help you

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and want the app to setup using the existing dot net framework version (4.6), because the app setup requires 4.7.2 version that the PC doesn't meet the requirements

Comment: Maybe this link helps you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30537535)